# How to calculate months with arrayformula in google script

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am able to calculate the monthly difference using dateif but not arrayformula

Example : Start Date: 5-Oct-2020
End date: 9-Jun-2021 month difference: using formula (DATEDIF(D3,E3 , "M")).

But I'm unable to use array formula to calculate as I wanted each row to be auto-calculated with dates.

Appreciate some help from Google experts!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(D3:D), DATEDIF(D3:D,E3:E, "M"),))
```

and see if that works?

---

### References

- [Arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [How do arrayformulas work?](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/)

Comment: Glad to hear @hrTech ! Maybe also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers